# Order of execution of jobs in delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have an rails app with the plugin https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

Some times the order in which the jobs are executed are not the same as in which they are created.

I would like the jobs to be executed in the same order as they are created, as in some cases for a job to execute, it is important that the previous job has been executed successfully.

Please help.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing exactly how you create your jobs but the only thing that affects the order of execution except for the created_at time is the priority set for the job. I don't know the differences between the tobi fork that you use and the collectiveidea fork but this is from the collectiveidea documentation:

> By default all jobs are scheduled with priority = 0, which is top priority. You can change this by setting Delayed::Worker.default_priority to something else. Lower numbers have higher priority.

And from migration:

> table.integer  :priority, :default => 0      # Allows some jobs to jump to the front of the queue

And you can of course specify the priority manually when you create your jobs.

Answer (score -1):

It is my understanding that jobs that fail are rescheduled for retries at a later time.

"On failure, the job is scheduled again in 5 seconds + N ** 4, where N is the number of retries." From Setup section of [README.textile](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job).

I assume the remaining jobs will be processed in the mean time. You may want to monitor your delayed_job table and see if any jobs have a last_error field value set to something other than NULL.

It may also depend on how many worker processes you have. delayed_job workers take the jobs out of the delayed_jobs table in order, but there is no guarantee that the workers will complete their tasks in order.